# Generate build without hashed file names in react production build

Tags: reactjs

When i try to generate production build, it generates chunks with hash. I do not want that hash to be included in the chunks (Shown in below attached screenshot). How i can achieve that.?

Chunks from npm run build

[image: Chunks from npm run build]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps: https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#output-filenames

```js
const path = require('path');
  const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
  const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

  module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    plugins: [
      // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/*']) for < v2 versions of CleanWebpackPlugin
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       title: 'Output Management',
      }),
    ],
    output: {
-     filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
+     filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally hashing help to identify if the newer version on the file is avaliable and to fetch the latest version, however, if you still want to disable hash output, try

`npm run build --output-hashing=none`