# React Scripts webpack config for background service workers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension in ReactJS and TS that uses a service worker. As per the new manifest V3 requirements I need to specify my service worker like this

```json
"background": {
  "service_worker": "serviceWorker.js"
}
```

In my `/src` folder which contains my TS code, `serviceWorker.ts` is contained within a folder called `background-scripts` to distinguish it from my normal content scripts.

However, when I build the extension with these changes and unpack the build folder generated by webpack and react-scripts (`react-scripts build` from CRA) the extension loader cannot find the `serviceWorker.js` file and fails to load my extension.

This is because the `webpack.config.json` file obfuscates the names of all of the TS files during build.

---

The `react-scripts` webpack config is in `/node-modules/react-scripts/config`. This file is  on the [react-scripts GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js).

---

It appeared I can filter individual files to keep their name

```js
filename: '[name]' === 'serviceWorker' ? 'static/js/[name].js' : isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js'
```

This is what I have so far. It doesn't work because I believe that `'[name]' === 'serviceWorker'` will always evaluate to false, but I don't understand how I get the filename property to compare them.

Comment: [Generate build without hashed file names in react production build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62749383)

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! This is certainly a step in the right direction. I have added my current code into my answer. Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can add custom entries as follows:

```js
entry: {
  main: paths.appIndexJs,
  serviceWorker: { import: "/path/to/service-worker", filename: "/folder/filename.js"  }
}
```

If you get the `cannot read 'filter' of undefined` error scroll down to line 686 and change the `entrypoints.main` to whatever you called your main bundle above.

If you have any questions please leave a comment.